# Fbprophet could not install in App Engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am new to App Engine. I am trying to deploy a webapp, which is working correctly in Heroku (Python). Once I try to import one of the packages that I need to run the web app (fbprophet form Python), the installing process gets stuck
I type in the cloud shell:

`python3.7 -m pip install fbprophet --user`

It starts correctly, without no problem, but after a long time the shell goes without connection and I need to restart it (see photo). In conclusion I cannot install this package...
I would like to know what's the problem or what I am doing wrong. If anyone could help me, I would be really pleased!
Thanks you in advance!

[image: Console]

Answer (score 2):

- As you can see [on the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html), to insall fbprophet  you need at least 4GB of memory to install it, and at least 2GB of memory to use it. As the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works) is a [GCE instance g1-small](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#sharedcore) , you were not able to install in it because it doesn't has enough memory to install fbprophet. In order to test it locally, deploy it in a machine which has at least 6GB of memory.
- I reproduced your issue and you're right it's not working for [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) , even though it makes sense because because GAE Standard doesn't have minimum 6GB memory limit to install "fbprophet" library.
- You can use App Engine Flexible, I deployed an app with "fbprophet" library in [App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings) and it's working correctly. Here you have the app.yaml and the requirements.txt I used -note that also you need to install the pystan library:

  - app.yaml

    ```
    runtime: python
    env: flex
    entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
    runtime_config:
      python_version: 3
    manual_scaling:
      instances: 1
    resources:
      cpu: 1
      memory_gb: 6
      disk_size_gb: 10
    ```
  - requirements.txt

    ```
    pystan==2.19.1.1
    fbprophet==0.5
    ```

Comment: Look interesting! Thank you for the help!

Comment: If it was useful for you, can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem of installing `fbprophet` while deploying my ml model in Heroku, I tried multiple ways to install the same by using `conda` etc in Heroku....

But the solution that worked for me is to just use python version `3.6.13`.

On the root folder of your app along with `requirements.txt` just add another file `runtime.txt` with the content `python-3.6.13` to mention the version of python to use for your app. Now deploy you code on Heroku and there won't be any issue with installing the `fbprophet` package.

Comment: Thank you so much